# Protractor How to compare 2 json files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have a Test scenario in which I am downloading a file and then I want to validate the content of downloaded JSON file with an expected JSON file.
How can I do that ?

I tried following :

```
var FilePath = path.join(global.downloadDir, "DownloadedFile.json")
var ExpectedFile = require('../TestData/json/TestFile');
var object = require(FilePath);
expect(object.body).toContain(ExpectedFile.body);
```

but this expect fails every time with this error :

```
Expected Object({ attributes: [ Object({ aggregate: 'count', field: 'display', hidden: false, label: 'Name', order: 'none', type: 'show', filter: Object({ filter: [ Object({ field: 'type', operator: 'eq', values: [ 'user_mail'
            ], not: false
          })
        ], operator: 'and'
      })
    }), Object({ aggregate: 'none', field: 'guid', hidden: true, internal: true, order: 'none', type: 'none'
    })
  ], data_types: [], detail: false, filter: Object({}), size: 500, data_types_group: 'test', context: 'test'
}) to contain Object({ attributes: [ Object({ aggregate: 'count', field: 'display', hidden: false, label: 'Name', order: 'none', type: 'show', filter: Object({ filter: [ Object({ field: 'type', operator: 'eq', values: [ 'user_mail'
            ], not: false
          })
        ], operator: 'and'
      })
    }), Object({ aggregate: 'none', field: 'guid', hidden: true, internal: true, order: 'none', type: 'none'
    })
  ], data_types: [], detail: false, filter: Object({}), size: 500, data_types_group: 'test', context: 'test'
}).
```

Comment: You should be aware that this kind of file comparison question is more suited the `nodejs` tag than the `protractor` tag as it purely a nodeJs operation. You will be much more likely to get suitable answers if you include that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below `npm` library does the job expected

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way and if performance is not an issue

```
const one = JSON.stringify(va1)

const two = JSON.stringify(va2)

one === two;
```